# The use of neural networks for data that has a trend

Tags: matlab, neural-network, time-series, stochastic

I have a signal that ranges from 0 to 1. It's always between these bounds, however, the signal changes over time (it has a trend). Thus its mean changes and standard deviation changes.

My goal is to determine how likely it is that the signal will stay within that range in the future. So I will decompose the signal into several features (like how fast it's increasing or decreasing, etc), and put all these data into a neural network. The signal itself has to be an input, because if the signal is really close to 1, and the signal is decreasing fast, then it's VERY likely that it will continue decreasing.

The question is, can I use a neural network to accomplish this without detrending the data? Or do I have to detrend it in order to make it an input?

Comment: As far as I know ALL analog or fuzzy-logic inputs need some sort of "out-of-bounds" filter. Tv's and radios and DVD/Blu-Ray all use digital filtering on their inputs. If possible oversampling is done to improve the results even more. "Out-of-bounds" signals can cause static or irrational behavior.

Comment: Sorry, but how does this answer the question?

Comment: Out-of-bounds by duration is no different then out-of-bounds from a brief spike. You need to experiment because your drifting into regions beyond our help. Your working with hardware and software that is a bit off-topic for us. We deal with software programming issues. We are not a laboratory.